# Get List of All PeerNameRecord's in a Cloud from C# System.Net.PeerToPeer

Tags: c#, .net, system.net

I would like to know if there is a way to use the `System.Net.PeerToPeer` namespace in C# to perform a lookup of all `System.Net.PeerToPeer.PeerNameRecord`'s on a `System.Net.PeerToPeer.Cloud`.

Ideally I want to list out everyone registered to the cloud without knowing their `System.Net.PeerToPeer.PeerName`.

I am familiar with the command line interface listed in the link below but I would like to have a method in C# in which I could generate the same output as the following command would generate.

`netsh p2p pnrp cloud show names`

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12213/Peer-Name-Resolution-PNRP-netsh

Comment: FYI: System.Net.PeerToPeer is obsolete on Win8+

Comment: Are there any other .NET local-link discovery libraries that would provide local client discovery in a way similar to mDNS?